# sqoop all table from mysql to Hive import

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am trying to import all tables from mysql schema to hive by using blow sqoop query:-

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://ip-172-31-20-247:3306/retail_db --username sqoopuser -P --hive-import --hive-import --create-hive-table -m 3
```

it is saying ,

```
18/09/01 09:24:52 ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Encountered IOException running import job: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory
 hdfs://ip-172-31-35-141.ec2.internal:8020/user/kumarrupesh2389619/categories already exists
```

Comment: Check this:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS yoursDataBase and please answer if it help

Comment: i have already removed all the tables before querying.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command

```
hdfs dfs -rmr /user/kumarrupesh2389619/categories
```

Your command is failing since the directory already exists.